# How to allow access to edit a field from a name thats in another field in IBM Domino Notes

Tags: formula, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I am trying to have a field on accessible by the name that is in another field on the form. So far I have created a section for the field, and have copied into the "Formula" Tab of the section properties "@Subset($UpdatedBy;1)". I need it to allow access from a name that is in another field, can someone please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're talking about a controlled access section. Are you trying to grant access to an additional name? And does the other field contain only that name? If so, you just need to use the list operator to add the name of the field to the formula:

```
@Subset($UpdatedBy;1) : anotherFieldContainingTheUserName;
```

Note that it's usually a good idea to also add an administrative role to the list of accessors so that there's a guarantee that you'll always be able to use the database ACL to grant access to the section if something goes wrong.  E.g.,

```
@Subset($UpdatedBy;1) : anotherFieldContainingTheUserName; "[MyAppAdmins]"
```